# Любить (?) люблю. Первый глагол — какой член предложения?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксический-разбор

Говорить (?) говорит. Есть (?) ел. Спать (?) спит. Любить (?) люблю. Хотеть (?) хочу. Писать (?) пишу. Спеть (?) споёт. Накормить (?) накормит.

1. Какой знак препинания здесь можно (или нужно) поставить?
2. Как разобрать данные предложения по составу? В них вторй глагол — сказуемое. А каким членом предложения является первый глагол?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Дискуссионный вопрос** (предлагаю принять участие).

1. Рассмотрим **похожий пример,** который есть в словаре и в Нацкорпусе.
   *По тому самому Андрей ему и не очень доверял, тем более что из господ, бывший учитель. **Но слушать ― слушал**.* М. А. Осоргин. Сивцев Вражек (1928).

***Слушать-то слушал, да ничего не понял.***

**ТО, частица.** 1. Употр. для подчёркивания и выделения в предложении слова, к которому относится. Я-то понимаю. Ночь-то какая тёплая! *Слушать-то слушал, да ничего не понял.* Где-то он сейчас? Что дальше-то делать будешь? [http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=то&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%82%D0%BE&all=x)

2. Мы видим **два варианта** оформления подобных предложений. *Но слушать ― слушал* (**сложное** предложение?). *Слушать-то слушал* (**простое** предложение с осложненным сказуемым?)
3. Сравним: ***Сам слушать не слушает и другим не дает.*** Это ПГС (простое глагольное сказуемое) — фразеологически свободное, но синтаксически связанное словосочетание, может иметь следующее строение и типовое значение: **повторение** одного и того же глагола **в разных формах** или однокоренных глаголов для усиления значения сказуемого: Сам спать не спит и другим не даёт. http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm#31201
4. ***Слушать ― слушал.*** Но в нашем случае приходится ставить тире, иначе структура предложения будет непонятной. И тогда **надо делать выбор.** Видимо, предложение нужно рассматривать как сложное, а не простое  с осложненным сказуемым.

В этом случае это **БСП со значением взаимообусловленности** (смысл такой: если говорить о «слушать», то он слушал). Дальше обычно следует противопоставление: хотя слушал, но не понял или не доверял словам.
Соответственно, здесь в БСП ставится  тире.

Рассмотрим каждое простое предложение.
***Слушать*** – это безличное инфинитивное предложение, главный член выражен независимым инфинитивом. Примеры: Тебе ходить. Молчать! Нам не забыть тех лет.

***Слышал*** – неполное двусоставное предложение с пропущенным подлежащим.
Грамматика: http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm#322

5. **Ответ:** *Говорить – говорит. Есть – ел. Спать – спит. Любить – люблю. Хотеть – хочу. Писать – пишу. Спеть – споёт. Накормить – накормит.*
   Тире ставится в сложном предложении (БСП). Сравнить: *Говорить-то говорит* (неполное простое предложение с осложненным сказуемым).